# Determining eigenvalues of a linear transformation on a field extension via embedding into $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations

I have been working on the following question:

> Suppose that $K$ is an extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. Let $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n:K\hookrightarrow\Bbb{C}$ be the distinct embeddings of $K$ into $\Bbb{C}$. Let $\alpha\in K$. Regarding $K$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$, let $\phi:K\to K$ be the linear transformation $\phi(x) = \alpha x$. Show that the eigenvalues of $\phi$ are $\sigma_1(\alpha),\dots,\sigma_n(\alpha)$.

I don't quite understand what exactly the question is asking. I know that $\phi$ is an endomorphism of $K$, but $\sigma_i$ maps $K$ into $\Bbb{C}$. How can eigenvalues of $\phi$ be in $\Bbb{C}$?

Perhaps the question is considering maps $\phi_i:\sigma_i(K)\to\sigma_i(K)$ by $x\mapsto \sigma_i(\alpha)x$, in which case the answer seems fairly straightforward? Of course $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is the eigenvalue for this map, just by definition.

The written answer I received, however, is far lengthier than this, and unfortunately is not very clear. Thus the above does not seem likely.

**Any clarification or hints would be appreciated.**

Comment: Recall that the eigenvalues of an operator are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. In your case you have an operator defined over $K$, whose characteristic polynomial will lie in $K[X]$. It is possible that its roots will lie in $\mathbb{C}$ but not in $K$, if that is what you are asking. As an example, I suggest you compute the eigenvalues for multiplication by $i$ in the field $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @GalPorat Are the eigenvalues of that map not $\pm i\in K$?

Comment: Sure, so now you may see that the claim you want to prove is true and makes sense in that particular case.

Comment: Sorry, I must be misunderstanding. I thought the example was a linear map of a finite field extension where the eigenvalues do not lie in that field. In the $K = \Bbb{Q}(i)$ case, both $\pm i$ do live in $K$.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. For an example where the eigenvalues do lie in the field, you should choose a field $K$ that is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. My first example was for you to see how the proposition holds in a specific case.